How to create a different URL for each dashboard page - NextJS 14
NextJS newbie here, so I apologize in advance if this has been asked before. I'm feeling really overwhelmed with all the information I'm finding and I'm not sure how to proceed.
I have a NextJS dashboard application. I'm loading each dashboard page as a component, based on what the user selects on the side menu. I'm trying to create a different URL route for each page on my dashboard so that users can access specific pages from the URL, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that. I would also like to be able to provide users with a direct URL to different dashboard pages. I haven't even got around to how I would do that.
So far I tried using the router from
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
but using this along with route.push() when a menu item is clicked triggers a whole dashboard reload, which I would like to avoid. I want for users to click on menu items, change the URL, and reload a specific component or "content section" inside the dashboard, as you would expect a dashboard to function.
What am I missing? Thanks in advance for the support
This is my folder structure:
app
├╴components
│ ├╴dashboard
│ │ └╴Dashboard.tsx
│ ├╴component / page 1 of dashboard 
│ │ └╴Component 1 / Page 1.tsx (importing this into the dashboard) 
│ └╴component / page 2 of dashboard (imported within dashboard) 
│   └╴Component 1 / Page 2.tsx (importing this into the dashboard) 
├╴layout.tsx 
└╴page.tsx (loads the dashboard component)

This is roughly how my dashboard code looks. I know it's not perfect but you can get the gist of what I'm doing.
'use client'

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import Component1 from '../Component 1/Component1'
import Component2 from '../Component 2/Component2'

export default function Dashboard() {
    const [selectedPage, setSelectedPage(component1)] = useState<string>('') 

  const handleMenuItemClick = (path: string) => {
    setSelectedPage(path) 
    renderContent()
    // INSERT HERE CODE TO CHANGE THE URL, NOT SURE YET
  }

  const renderContent = () => {
    switch (url) {
      case '/component1':
        return <div class="component1">Component 1</div>
      case '/component2':
        return <div class="component">Component 1</div>              
      default:
        return <div>Dashboard home/div>
    }
  }

  return (
    // Navigation, where each menu item runs handleMenuItemClick

    // Main Content
      {renderContent()}
  )
}


check this url https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing

I think you are asking question about routing. You don't need to use router.push(). Insted in Next.js each folder inside app directory represents a route.
  app
   posts
    page.tsx  (can be accessed by localhost:3000/posts)
   setting
    page.tsx (localhost:3000/setting)
   create
    page.tsx
   page.tsx localhost:3000/) [index page]

Learn More on routing at: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing
